# É possível desenvolver Agentes similares a Aglets usando EJB 3.0?

Tags: java, ejb

Á alguns anos eu trabalhei um projeto de mestrado de análise e manutenção de infraestrutura de Redes utilizando [Agentes Móveis](http://www.cic.unb.br/~jhcf/MyBooks/ciber/doc-ppt-html/AgentesMoveis.html) baseados em [Aglets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aglets).

Hoje estou projetando um novo sistema que terá a necessidade de agentes capazes de se deslocar entre agencias/servidores de forma análoga ao método usado no Aglets.

É possível obter tal habilidade com EJBs? Há outros frameworks capazes de oferecer recursos similares?

Informações de apoio

- [Framework Aglets](http://sourceforge.net/projects/aglets/)
- [Mobile Agents with Java: The Aglet API - CiteSeer](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CC4QFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.96.1463%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&ei=j-htVb26H4GDgwTXuYGQCg&usg=AFQjCNE1SI7xg6Tjn4aUEXLnY5rc6Wz8dw&sig2=VS5UTmwKwFGYdluED_Xh0g&bvm=bv.94455598,d.eXY)
- [The Architecture of Aglets - Javaworld](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077639/core-java/the-architecture-of-aglets.html)
- [Dissertação do Professor Inácio Dutra](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDwQFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.uece.br%2Fmpcomp%2Findex.php%2Farquivos%2Fdoc_download%2F177-dissertacao-18&ei=GuptVarOB8K0ggSUyIHwCQ&usg=AFQjCNFhrhxZGtvF65FQQet1LKlGCJdR9g&sig2=6YxDBNlCNfD-7FtrypTq_Q&bvm=bv.94455598,d.eXY)

Comment: Gostaria de sugerir duas novas tags, que seria úteis para indexar tópicos como desta pergunta:

agentes-moveis e grids-computacionais

Comment: `[1]` e `[2]` são links? Tem como informá-los?

Comment: Me desculpe @BrunoCésar, esqueci os links.